# Creating a distance table (staircase table)

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

Is there a way to automate the creation of a distance table as such? E.g., the folowing table expresses how far towns are from each other, therefore I'm not interested in the distance of a town with itself, rather than the distance with the other towns. In particular, I'd rather not re-set the layout each time I'm adding a new city or removing it and, if possible, each cell should be defined as

```
\scalentry{city1}{city2}{value}
```

I find no package doing something like that, but I might be wrong. If that simplifies the question, having a preliminary command `\headerlist{city1,city2,city3,...}` for deciding the appearance order of the cities would also work. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I neither know of a package doing this, but have a look at the `nicematrix` package: https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix?lang=en for the final visualization.

Comment: Thanks, it seems a very nice package for embellishing tables! NiceTabular seems the right thing, even though it seems not possible to add some labels to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility using tikz. I created the command you need and another for the cities (I think it's easier to assign numbers to the cities).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup   {output-decimal-marker={,}}

\def\l{1}   % cell size
\def\d{0.1} % cell distance

\newcommand{\scalentry}[3] % city1 (number, row), city2 (number, column), distance
{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,2))}
  \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0                                                                                   
    \draw               ({#2*(\l+\d)},{#1*(\l+\d)}) rectangle ++ (\l,\l);
  \else 
    \draw[fill=gray!20] ({#2*(\l+\d)},{#1*(\l+\d)}) rectangle ++ (\l,\l);
  \fi
  \node at ({#2*(\l+\d)+0.5*\l},{#1*(\l+\d)+0.5*\l}) {\num{#3}};
}
\newcommand{\city}[2] % name, position
{%
  \node[above right] at ({#2*(\l+\d)},{(#2+1)*(\l+\d)-0.25*\l}) {#1};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0,-1)}]
  \city{Argenta}   {1}
  \city{Boccaleone}{2}
  \city{San Biagio}{3}
  \city{Bando}     {4}
  % ...
  \scalentry{2}{1} {4.2}
  \scalentry{3}{1} {4.8}
  \scalentry{3}{2} {9}
  \scalentry{4}{1} {6}
  \scalentry{4}{2} {7.8}
  \scalentry{4}{3}{10.8}
  % ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the (partial) table  is the following:
[image]

Comment: Yes, the assumptions are more than legit, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution based only on TeX primitives:

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\scalentry#1#2#3{\sdef{c:#1:#2}{#3}\sdef{c:#2:#1}{#3}}
\def\cs#1{\csname#1\endcsname}

\def\headerlist#1{\par\def\headerlistL{}\headerlistA#1,,}
\def\headerlistA#1,{\ifx,#1,\else \headerlistB{#1}\expandafter\headerlistA\fi}
\def\headerlistB#1{\def\headerlistT{#1}%
   \expandafter\headerlistC\headerlistL,%
   #1\vskip1pt
   \edef\headerlistL{\headerlistL#1,}}
\def\headerlistC#1,{\ifx,#1,\else 
   \printitem{\cs{c:\headerlistT:#1}}\expandafter\headerlistC \fi}
\def\printitem#1{\leavevmode \lower3pt
  \vbox{\hrule\hbox to3em{\vrule\hss#1\strut\hss\vrule}\hrule}\kern2pt}

%% Test

\scalentry{Argenta}{Boccaleone}{4,2}
\scalentry{Argenta}{San Biagio}{4,8}
\scalentry{Boccaleone}{San Biagio}{9}
\scalentry{Argenta}{Bando}{6}
\scalentry{Boccaleone}{Bando}{7,8}
\scalentry{San Biagio}{Bando}{10,8}

Prints the table:
\headerlist{Argenta,Boccaleone,San Biagio,Bando}

Prints another table:
\headerlist{Boccaleone,San Biagio,Bando,Argenta}
```

Comment: This solution gives me the following error: ```! Undefined control sequence. \n <argument> \cs \n                {c:\headerlistT :Argenta} \n l.31 ...rlist{Argenta,Boccaleone,San Biagio,Bando}```

Comment: Sorry, I tested it on a format with my macros (including `\cs`). I corrected the answer.